# Google Chrome extension Manifest Version 2 - Executing the initialisation script

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest

Manifest version 2 Content Security Policy do not let extension to run inline script. That mean I can't use

```
      <script>Code Here</script>
      <button onclick="And here">
```

When I used manifest version 1 my popup.html executed some code on it's load ether this way:

```
      <body onload='init()'>
```

or like this

```
      <script>init()</script>
```

Now I can see the only way - to put a button inside popup.html and press it manually to do the initialisation. What am I getting wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creat a popup.js file, and extract your scripts into this file, and add listener like this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init());
```

Then include the popup.js file into the popup.html file.